# Azure Remote app: How do I evaluate the user that is running my application?

Tags: vb.net, azure, remoteapp

I have a simple VB.net console application that displays the current user, waits for key input, and then exits. It uses the following call to display the information:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Name.ToString()
```

If I create a remote app hosting this application, and create an azure user that has rights to run the remote app such as;

**thisisa@test.onmicrosoft.com**

When this user connects to the remote app the output of the line of code above would look something like;

**YLSDAAYU0007\thisisa_000**

Is there anyway of reading the user running the remoteapp at the time? in this case, I am looking to obtain **thisisa@test.onmicrosoft.com** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catalin from the RemoteApp team here. You have stumbled across one of our implementation details here :)

Windows does not allow automatic login with Azure Active Directory (AAD) users: they only allow users that have Microsoft Accounts or domain accounts in case the collection is domain joined. We are working around this limitation by creating a local user on the VM and logging in with that user instead of the AAD user.

If you have any more questions about this, feel free to contact me: catalda ＠ microsoft com